# Writing chars to pipe in C

Tags: c, char, signals, fork, pipe

I have the following program which is basically reading chars from keyboard (getch() does this without the need to click 'ENTER', function is taken from here:[Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr))
, and then if the char is one of the legal moves (LEFT, RIGHT, etc) it is writing it to a pipe, which draw.out is reading from.

draw.out is reading the input it recieved and printing to screen. (assume this program works fine, I assure the problem is in the following code only).

The problem is, that:

1. draw.out is acting like it has recieving my input over and over again. Which means, for some reason, even though I press, for exmaple, DOWN key only once, it sends draw.out as if I clicked many times on it.
2. After sending one input, I cannot send anymore, as if the loop is stopping.

Tried to break my head over this for many hours... I'd really appreciate help.

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
pid_t child_pid;
int fda[2];
if(pipe(fda)<0)
    perror("pipe error");

if((child_pid=fork())<0)
    perror("fork error");
else
{
    //if we're in father
    if(child_pid>0)
    {
        char c=' ';

        //close read side
        close(fda[0]);

        while(c!=QUIT)
        {
            //get an instruction from keyboard
            while(c!=ROTATE && c!=LEFT && c!=RIGHT &&
                    c!=DOWN && c!=QUIT)
            {
                c=getch();
            }

            //write the instruction to pipe
            write(fda[1],&c,1);
            //notify the child
            kill(child_pid,SIGUSR2);

        }
    }
    //if we're in child process
    else
    {
        dup2(fda[0],0);
        close(fda[0]);
        close(fda[1]);
        execl("./draw.out","./draw.out",NULL);
    }
}

//close everything
close(fda[0]);
close(fda[1]);
return 0;
}

//this function works well in linux with tsch installed or in SSH bash shell
char getch()
{
char buf = 0;
struct termios old = {0};
if (tcgetattr(0, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr()");
old.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
old.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
old.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
old.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
if (read(0, &buf, 1) < 0)
        perror ("read()");
old.c_lflag |= ICANON;
old.c_lflag |= ECHO;
if (tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) < 0)
        perror ("tcsetattr ~ICANON");
return (buf);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have sent the char `c` you need to set it to a value other than `ROTATE`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `DOWN`.

If you don't `getch()` will never be called a second time...

So at the end of the outer `while` (just after `kill`) or at the start of the loop (just before the `while` containing the `getch()` call) add something like

```
if (c != QUIT)
  c = ' ';
```

Comment: Oh god! thank you very much! 6 hours and alot of head ache! I feel so relieved. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the while loop to a do/while loop to ensure getch() is always called at least once.

```
do
{
    c = getch();
}
while (c != ROTATE && c != LEFT && c != RIGHT && c != DOWN && c != QUIT);
```